# combining vectors in r

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataset that has repeated measures within a plot. The data-set looks like this

[image]

And I want to extract all the rows which begin with 1 (1a, 1b, 1c). Samples were measured from these plots 15 times, with three repeated measures taken during each sampling event. So the final `data.frame` should have a total of 135 observations (3x3x15).

This is the code I have used...

```
Station1 <- BISC1FeldsParData[BISC1FeldsParData$Plot == c("1a", "1b", "1c"),]
```

Yet the resulting `data.frame` only has 45 observations. It seems as though I lose the replicates within each sampling event for each of the plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace `==` with `%in%`:

```
Station1 <- BISC1FeldsParData[BISC1FeldsParData$Plot %in% c("1a", "1b", "1c"), ]
```

---

Or we can use `grep`:

```
Station1 <- BISC1FeldsParData[grep("^1", BISC1FeldsParData$Plot), ]
```

Explanation: The regexp string `"^1"` matches entries that start with `"1"`.

---

Or use `subset`

```
Station1 <- subset(BISC1FeldsParData, Plot %in% c("1a", "1b", "1c"))
```

---

Or `dplyr::filter`

```
Station1 <- dplyr::filter(BISC1FeldsParData, Plot %in% c("1a", "1b", "1c"))
```

Comment: Much appreciated!